# image src according to link end

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I have a image hosting, and would like to create a page where the image is hosted by user and advertisements on the site appear on the same page.

Like this for example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJfAF.jpg

For this gostria whether there is any script where the **SRC** tag foce **< img >** equal to the end of the link.

Thus, for example:

my image host/File I want to create.html/hosted image.png

Since

my image host/File I want to create.html < File I want to create an object having **< img >** whose **SRC** = hosted image.png

*I'm sorry if the translation was not good. But can anyone help me?*

Comment: This is very hard to follow, and you don't state an actual problem, or what you have tried already. It is also always a good idea to include relevant samples of your code, both HTML and javascript.

Comment: I want to help you but I read the question 3 times and no clue what it is asking

Comment: @Gadgetster
I wonder if there is a script to set the value of SRC ugual the end of the link. 
Example: mysite. com / scrpt.html = http://mysite. com/img.png 
and on that page the script 
<img src="http://mysite. com/img.png"> 
because of the link end with http://mysite. com/img.png 
of which may vary for http://mysite. com/img.png Quaker another link.

Comment: You are trying to making some links equal? no idea what you said. I am sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i am assuming you want to get the extension of the image that is posted in a form? if so try this

```
<?php
$path= $_FILES['image']['name']; // $_FILES['image'] is the file for the form name "image"


$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext = strtolower($ext);
echo $ext
?>
```

Comment: It really is difficult to explain using the google translator 

Thanks to all who try to help, but I'll try to use a forum in Portuguese. 

Thank you!